# Data within Ext.Panel without XTemplate?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

is there a way to apply data to "regular" fields and subitems without using the an XTemplate?

My code looks like:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
   data: myDataBlock
   defaults: {
      data: myDataBlock
   }
   title: 'Name: {name}'
   items: [{
       xtype: 'panel',
       title: 'more: {moreData}'
   }]
});
```

What would be required to have proper substitudes with the data form "myDataBlock" ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "regular" fields?

The `data` property of Panel is the initial data you want rendered, and it gets rendered using a template. You can specify a custom template for rendering if you wish, but either way it has to use a template so that ExtJS knows how to render your content.

Look at the source code for `Component`:

```
if (this.data) {
    this.tpl[this.tplWriteMode](contentTarget, this.data);
    delete this.data;
}
```

> **data**: The initial set of data to apply to the tpl to update the
>   content area of the Component.

Comment: I guess you haven't looked into my example. Every panel e.g. has a "title" property and I'd like to refer to the data from that one too without using the additional templates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create the panel dynamically by a data block to set the properties like `title` etc...

If so, my suggestion is write your own panel class that extends `Ext.Panel` and do the things before its components is initiated.

Sample:

```
//Define your own panel class
MyPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
  width: 300,
  height: 150,
  initComponent: function(){
     if(this.data){
        Ext.apply(this,{
           title: 'Name: '+ this.data.title,
           items: [
              {
                 xtype: 'panel',
                 html: 'more: '+ this.data.moreData
              }
           ]
        });
     }
     MyPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
  }
});

//Use the customized panel
var p = new MyPanel({
   data: {title:'my title', moreData: 'other data'},
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

By the way, Template is only used to render the content of a panel in a plain way. In your case it's not proper to use Template because it has nothing to do with the config property nor the items of a panel.